# Не работает "hidden" в bootstrap 4

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Не скрывает элементы в bootstrap 4, при подключении bootstrap 3 все работает хорошо

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>Example</h2>
<p>Resize this page to see how the text below changes:</p>
<div class="hidden-xs bg-danger">This text is hidden on an EXTRA SMALL screen.</div>
<div class="hidden-sm bg-info">This text is hidden on a SMALL screen.</div>
<div class="hidden-md bg-warning">This is text hidden on a MEDIUM screen.</div>
<div class="hidden-lg bg-success">This is text hidden on a LARGE screen.</div>
```

Comment: похоже в bootstrap4 нет классов hidden

Comment: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/#available-classes

Comment: Вы сначала проверьте правильно вы его подключили.

Comment: Забавно, в вопросе используется ссылка не beta версию, а в примере на alpha-6. Причем @soledar в beta версии **нет** классов с hidden указанных в миграции

Comment: да, не посмотрел версию - для beta - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844579/4419684

Comment: @soledar10, переведешь? а то у меня не полный ответ получается :-)

Comment: @Grundy здесь вроде и переводить нечего, разве что добавить список классов

Comment: @soledar10, там вступление есть, и да, самое главное список классов, которые эквивалентны в 4 и 3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В beta версии [в очередной раз все переиграли](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#responsive-utilities) и теперь группа классов имеет вид:

```
.d-*-none
```

Стоит так же обратить внимание, что теперь условия применяются не на конкретный диапазон, например, только на `medium`, а на `medium` и больше. Поэтому был убрал класс с `xs`, так как сейчас это эквивалентно *не показываться на экранах xs и больше*, что означает - никогда не показывать.

Пример:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h2>Example</h2>
<p>Resize this page to see how the text below changes:</p>
<div class="d-none bg-danger">This text is hidden on an EXTRA SMALL screen and larger.</div>
<div class="d-sm-none bg-info">This text is hidden on a SMALL screen and larger.</div>
<div class="d-md-none bg-warning">This is text hidden on a MEDIUM screen and larger.</div>
<div class="d-lg-none bg-success">This is text hidden on a LARGE screen and larger.</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Классы `hidden-*` и `visible-*` в бета-версии Bootstrap 4 удалены. Если вы хотите скрыть элемент на определенных уровнях или контрольных точках в Bootstrap 4, используйте классы отображения `d- *`.

- `hidden-xs-down` = `d-none` `d-sm-block`
- `hidden-sm-down` = `d-none` `d-md-block`
- `hidden-md-down` = `d-none` `d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg-down` = `d-none` `d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl-down` = `d-none` (same as hidden)
- `hidden-xs-up` = `d-none` (same as hidden)
- `hidden-sm-up` = `d-sm-none`
- `hidden-md-up` = `d-md-none`
- `hidden-lg-up` = `d-lg-none`
- `hidden-xl-up` = `d-xl-none`
- `hidden-xs` (only) = `d-none` `d-sm-block` (same as `hidden-xs-down`)
- `hidden-sm` (only) = `d-block` `d-sm-none` `d-md-block`
- `hidden-md` (only) = `d-block` `d-md-none` `d-lg-block`
- `hidden-lg` (only) = `d-block` `d-lg-none` `d-xl-block`
- `hidden-xl` (only) = `d-block` `d-xl-none`
- `visible-xs` (only) = `d-block` `d-sm-none`
- `visible-sm` (only) = `d-none` `d-sm-block` `d-md-none`
- `visible-md` (only) = `d-none` `d-md-block` `d-lg-none`
- `visible-lg` (only) = `d-none` `d-lg-block` `d-xl-none`
- `visible-xl` (only) = `d-none` `d-xl-block`

Оригинал - [Stackoverflow EN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844579/4419684)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, пробовал старые значения hidden-sm и visible-sm , они для версии 4.1 не работают.